# communicate with angularjs model from external script

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried every way I can think of to trigger the ng-model functions for my form. I am using the bootstrap datepicker. I need the bootstrap datepicker to trigger an ng-model value update when the date is picked can some please tell me how to interact with the ng-model using an external library or an external event?

Here is my code sample.

It is not very complex.

```js
/// <reference path="../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />
var app = angular.module("DatePick", []);
var doc = document;
app.controller("AppCtrl", [
 "$scope", "$q", "$http",
 function($scope, $q, $http){
  var appCtrl = this;
  
  appCtrl.name = "Jesse App";
  
  $scope.$on("pickerChange", function(evt, data){
   
  $scope.$apply(function(){
   
   $scope.form[data.key] = data.value;
   console.log(data);
  })
  
   
  })
 }
]);

var $scope;
doc.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e){
 
 angular.bootstrap(doc.querySelector("html"), ["DatePick"]);
 
 var element = document.querySelector("form");
 
 $scope = angular.element(element).scope();
 

 
});

$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $("input:text").datepicker().change(function(e){
  
  $scope.$emit("pickerChange", {key:$(e.currentTarget).attr('name'), value:$(e.currentTarget).val()})

 })
 
 $(".trigger").click(function(e){
  
  var input = $("input[type=text]");
  input.val('xxx');
  input.trigger('input');
  
 })
 
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
 <div class="container">
  <h3>{{app.name}}</h3> 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit et, nulla, voluptates adipisci commodi, itaque ipsam earum hic ipsa qui nam. Itaque nulla, aut quod sit dignissimos explicabo laborum, mollitia!
 </div>
 <div class="container">
  <form novalidate name="form">
   <div ng-show="form.date.$dirty">
    <div ng-show="form.date.$valid">valid</div>
    <div ng-show="form.date.$invalid">invalid</div>
   </div>
   <input type="text" name="date" ng-model="date" class="form-control" ng-pattern="/[\d|\/]{5,}/" required>
   <div ng-show="form.date2.$dirty">
    <div ng-show="form.date2.$valid">valid</div>
    <div ng-show="form.date2.$invalid">invalid</div>
   </div>
   <input type="text" name="date2" ng-model="date2" class="form-control" ng-pattern="/[\d|\/]{5,}/" required>
  </form>
  <div class="btn btn-primary trigger">trigger</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The reason for the trigger button was that I was trying to see if I could use jquery to trigger the input and get angular to update the model but it is necessary.

Comment: The models activate just fine. What you're doing wrong is the `form.date.$dirty`, `form.date.$valid`, `form.date.$invalid` calls. Try putting `{{date}} {{date2}}` in the HTML, and you'll see it update when you pick a date.

Comment: OK that makes sense but how do I get date and date2 to validate on the form.  It's like angular doesn't know about it even though I am using $scope.$apply() to make sure it knows the values have been changed.

Comment: would it make more sense to add the date picker values to a factory or a service so that the updates are applied to the binding?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the bootstrap [datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) from the `ui-bootstrap` directive library.
It has angular integration and you can use pure angular binding with `ng-model`.

Comment: I am going to use that as a last resort. I am not so much focused on it being the bootstrap date picker.  I am more concerned about being able to communicate with the model from the external script.  It could really be jquery itself, or even another script.

Comment: Angular is build to work with directives. The ui boostrap library has most of the normal boostrap components as directives to create a seamless integration. 

IMHO one is using an anti-pattern in angular when trying to hook things up like this. I'd do it the angular way instead and make it easier to maintain and understand.

Comment: I started learning Angular extensively about 18 months ago.  I'd recommend that you listen to @BjørnSørensen.  It was very difficult to let go of certain development paradigms that I came to rely on prior to working with Angular, however bucking Angular conventions causes a lot of pain later on down the road.  It's opinionated and gives you an ear full if you argue with it.